# Ubuntu 9.10 installer cd-image with embedded updates

Tags: ubuntu, installation

Unfortunately there are many bugs and imperfections in original Ubuntu 9.10 cd-image. Some of them make impossible the correct installation.

Is there any way to obtain installation image with embedded updates?

Comment: Not to doubt your assertions. But could you be more specific? I would like to know, I haven't had any problems.

Comment: I had some trouble installing from a DVD (grub install failed) but the CD iso from Distrowatch worked fine.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/97193/should-canonical-revise-their-ubuntu-half-year-release-policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:
[LiveCD Customization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) or
[LiveCD Customization2](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-customize-your-ubuntu-live-cd) or 
[Remastersys](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/creating-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-with-remastersys.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could do with with a netboot CD, available for download from the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/WindowsServerNetboot) by following the instuctions at the link, but I must admit I'd not heard of major issues with the 9.10 installation process, and I'd expect a 9.11 to have been relased if it was widespread.

What kind of issues are you having? Maybe you should raise a seperate question for them if you haven't already.

Comment: There'll never be a 9.11 because Ubuntu numbering is not about bumping values up by 1, but about year.month, so 9.11 would be a release from November 2009. However, LTS releases have bugfix releases, such as 8.04.3 for the 3rd bugfix pack for the 8.04 (April 2008) release.

Comment: Sure, but if 9.10 had been a disaster, then I'd of expected a fixed release within a few weeks (maybe it'd slip into 9.12), but since it hasn't happened I'm wondering what macropas' problems are.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/97193/should-canonical-revise-their-ubuntu-half-year-release-policy

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to make a repository copy on a thumb drive  and point `apt` to it:

> deb file:///media/thumb/ karmic main

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. Have you considered other ways of installing, for example using PXE with a netinstall image?